# Como fazer o Jboss escutar as modificações em IDE diferente da que está?

Tags: java, jboss

O problema é o seguinte, tenho o jboss no eclipse, mas não gosto dela para trabalhar com HTML, CSS e JS prefiro usar o Visual Code!
Ao subir a aplicação faço a modificação usando Visual Code mas o Jboss só percebe a modificação depois que é feita no eclipse! Como faço ele perceber minhas modificações no Visual Code e não somente no Eclipse ?